# How to delete a many-to-many association between two entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have two entities and a bi-directional many-to-many relation between them mapped in Hibernate.

The xml configuration looks like this in both classes:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.MyEntity">
        <set name="myOtherEntities" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="entity_id"/>
            <many-to-many column="my_other_entity_id" class="com.example.OtherEntity" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I terminate **only** the association between them without deleting any of the entities?

If I `clear()` the set in `MyEntity` and call `Session.flush()` then the `MyOtherEntity` objects get deleted but I only want to clear the records in the join table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways using which you can do this.

1) Using Hibernate Native Query
2) Using Hibernate `createSQLQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the delete orphan property that trigger the deletion for `MyOtherEntity`.

Should be replaced by `cascade="all"`

Regards.

Addendum : Hibernate doc indicate in chapter 11 that cascade `all-delete-orphan` should not be used with `ManytoMany` relations.

Answer (score 0):

The correct setting in this scenario is `cascade="none"`.

Hibernate in `many-to-many` relations has to work with 3 tables. `MyEntity`, `OtherEntity` and pairing table `MyEntity-OtherEntity`.

#### Pair table

Once we create the relation by adding `MyEntity` instance into the `OtherEntity` collection and vice versa, Hibernate will *hiddenly* insert the record into pairing table.
Once we remove some instance form the collection, Hibernate will remove the record from pairing table.

This is done, with the setting `cascade="none"`. Becuase it is the only way how to handle that. There is no cascading from the perspective of the pairing table

#### The cascading

Any cascading applied on `many-to-many` relation, does not apply to pairing table, but to the second end. In most cases, this is what we do not want. We should have separated DAO for `MyEntity` management and `OtherEntity` management.

In rare cases, when during update of one end, we want to insert, update or even delete the other... we can use cascading. But this is not our case.

Use this setting in this scenario

```
<set name="myOtherEntities" cascade="none">
```

See more [8.3.4. Many-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m)